# Can we use partner license for UAT and Test Environment?

Tags: licensing

We are using sitecore 9.1. We have a partner license to develop the Sitecore application.

Can we use the same license for UAT and Test environments? Or is another license required for that?

Both environment will be hosted in azure.

Answer (score 5):

You mention that you've got a partner license to develop the application. I believe from a legal standpoint the partner can use the partner license for development, but when client can access (for instance to test) the client's license should be used.

Obviously if the partner is the client you would use the same partner license - just be mindful that you renew your license before August 30th every year, as that's when partner licenses expire and can lead to a yellow screen of death (client licenses will not expire).

As Tomáš Knaifl mentions in his answer, keep in mind that in most cases there'll be a license agreement which specifies the limit to production and non-production servers. I've recently written a blog post on Sitecore's licensing where you can find a bit more details on when something is a production vs non-production server which you can [find here](https://trayek.wordpress.com/2018/05/09/demystifying-sitecores-licensing/). 
The gist is that when you've got perpetual license, only CM and CD is classed as production server (so processing/reporting is not), while on subscription anything that touches live (including processing/reporting) is classed as production server.

Answer (score 5):

If you are a partner, you can find details about the partner license outlined on SPN here:

- http://spn.sitecore.net/Partner%20Resources/Partner%20License.aspx

The partner license statement on SPN qualifies your scenario with a usage clause. Essentially, are they 'internal developmen/test' environments or is it being used by the customer/client.

> The partner license cannot be used for:
>
> **Customer Use:** No access or use of the partner license by a customer is allowed
>
> **Development and maintenance of Sitecore Solutions for Customers:** Unless a license has been purchased and issued before development work begins

So, in your scenario of test/UAT, as long as the customer has already purchased a license from Sitecore and will not be able to access these environments, then your partner license usage is okay.

If you have a specific scenario not outlined in the guide on SPN, you can always reach out to your partner manager to ask questions.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which license and how many licenses customer has for “non-production” usage. You should use customers license for that purpose. You cannot use your company partner license.

For example - one of our customer had consumption based license which means that number of usage in production is not limited.

But for no -production usage, they have only 4 licenses. So, uat+ dev cannot have more than 4 usages . By usage - it means that any standalone instance of cm, cd, rep, prc, exm delivery consumes one license. So if you setup 2 environments , overy with 1 cd and 1 cm, you need 4 licenses.

And be carefull - if you will use features like auto scaling and so on - every scaled instance needs its own license.

This year, new licensing model was introduced for non production usages - based on environments. So, you can have licenses, for example, 3 environments with unlimited instances.

Answer (score 2):

***The partner license can be used for:***

- Internal research and development
- Demonstrations of the Sitecore Products
- Only with written authorization from Sitecore
- Development and maintenance of Sitecore Solutions for Customers
- Only when a license has been purchased and issued before development work begins
  Management of the Solution Partner’s own web properties for up to one (1) public-facing website on* up to four (4) production delivery and/or management Server installations

***The partner license cannot be used for:***

- ***Customer Use:*** No access or use of the partner license by a customer is allowed
- ***Development and maintenance of Sitecore Solutions for Customers***: Unless a license has been purchased and issued before development work begins